# Calculating premiums to charge to policy holders using different claim rates in R

Tags: r, poisson

I am calculating premiums to be charged to policy holders using 8 different claim rates (probabilities of making a claim), using a poisson process. The values using this code are :
568.48 625.44 684.34 732.58 772.40 802.90 832.46 851.66
These values are different from the correct values I get in Excel and theoretically calculated:
517.4 550.26 601.14 650.96 705.86 757.4 796.18 829.64
Can anyone try correct the R code to get these values?

```
a <- array(0:0,dim=c(21,5000)) # over time period t=21, 5000 policy holders
d<-array(1:5) 
e<-array(1:5) # five discount levels used
p<-array(1:8) # premium charged for 8 separate claim rates
z=0
e[1]=1 # discount 0%
e[2]=.8 # discount 20%
e[3]=.7 # discount 30%
e[4]=.6 # discount 40%
e[5]=.5 # discount 50%

for (l in seq(0.1,0.8,.1)){ # claim rates 0.1,0.2,0.3...0.8
  for (j in 1:20){
    for (i in 1:5000) {
      b<-min(2,rpois(1,l))
      if (b==2) {a[j+1,i]=0}     # b is the number of claims made, if 2 or more, drop down to 0% discount
      if (b==0) {a[j+1,i]=min(5,a[j,i]+1)} # if 0 claims made, go to next level of discount
      if (b==1) {a[j+1,i]=max(0,a[j,i]-1)} # if 1 claim made, drop back one discount level
    }
  }
  for (k in 1:5){
    d[k]=1000*e[k]*(length(subset(a[5,],a[5,]==k-1))/5000)
  }
  z=z+1;p[z]=sum(d)
}
p   # premium charged at each claim rate 0.1,0.2, ... , 0.8
```

Comment: sorry e[1] is actual 0% not 10%

Comment: Yeah so what's your programming question about?

Comment: Shauna, please give us all of the parameters of the problem.  There may be problems with the syntax or formulas that we can't troubleshoot without understanding the whole space.

Comment: I get different numbers than you listed too.  But that should be expected no? You're calling a function that generates random values from a Poisson distribution and thus will get different `b` values.  Every time you run this code you will get a different answer... Without knowing how you did this calculation in Excel, we can't say if this is "wrong".

Comment: So the premium values will vary every time the code is implemented in R ya, but they wont change to a great extent, maybe one or two values above or below. The values from excel are about 30-40 values off the values from R which makes me think I have made a mistake with the code.

Comment: So what I'm actually doing:

Comment: So what I'm actually doing: x=#claims ~poi(LAMBDA). Lambda =0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8. There are five discount levels 0%,20%,30%,40%,50%.  Trandition rules that apply: if a policy holer makes a claim in one year, they move back one discount level, or stay at 0, if they make no claims in 1 year, they move up one discount level or stay at 50% discount, if they make 2 or more claims in 1 year, the move back to or stay at the 0% discount level.

Comment: Now, I want to calculate the average premium charged for a policy holder with claim rate lambda. This is done theoretically by obtaining an equilibrium (pi0,p1,pi2,pi3,pi4,pi5). Where pi0 denotes the number of policyholders at discount level 0%, pi2 denotes the number of policy holders at discount level 20%. The avg premium is calculated theoretically as: 1000((1)pi0,(0.8)p1,(0.7)pi2,(0.6)pi3,(0.5)pi4), with a general formula for each pi and so can sub in different lamda values each time 0.1,0.2,...,0.8. I want to do this now through R? Does that help?

Comment: 21 years, so if i have (j in 1:21), i get an error subscript out of bounds?

Answer (score 1):

You have a slight problem in your code, with respect to your discount levels.  You have 5 discount levels, 0%, 20%, 30%, 40% and 50%.  In your loop, however, you allow 6: because you're setting people with 2 or more claims back to 0, you're allowing 6 levels of discount, 0,1,2,3,4,5.  When you calculate the d vector, you iterate from 1:5, but you're really iterating from 0:4, because you're comparing to k-1, which means you're missing your highest-discount group.

There are a couple ways to fix it, but the simplest is to change your if(b==0) line

```
if (b==0) {a[j+1,i]=min(4,a[j,i]+1)} # if 0 claims made, go to next level of discount
```

That should do it.

Also, from a theoretical perspective, why is your a-matrix 21 rows deep (implying 21 years), but you're only iterating over the first 5, and then ignoring the 6th year?  I would make the loop go 1:20, and then check the 21st row, rather than the 5th.  The full code I used is given below:

```
a <- array(0:0,dim=c(21,5000)) # over time period t=21, 5000 policy holders
d<-array(1:5) 
e<-array(1:5) # five discount levels used
p<-array(1:8) # premium charged for 8 separate claim rates
z=0
e[1]=1 # discount 0%
e[2]=.8 # discount 20%
e[3]=.7 # discount 30%
e[4]=.6 # discount 40%
e[5]=.5 # discount 50%

for (l in seq(0.1,0.8,.1)){ # claim rates 0.1,0.2,0.3...0.8
  for (j in 1:20){
    for (i in 1:5000) {
      b<-min(2,rpois(1,l))
      if (b==2) {a[j+1,i]=0}     # b is the number of claims made, if 2 or more, drop down to 0% discount
      if (b==1) {a[j+1,i]=max(0,a[j,i]-1)} # if 1 claim made, drop back one discount level
      if (b==0) {a[j+1,i]=min(4,a[j,i]+1)} # if 0 claims made, go to next level of discount
    }
  }    
  for (k in 1:5){
    d[k]=1000*e[k]*(length(subset(a[21,],a[21,]==(k-1)))/5000)
  }
  z=z+1;p[z]=sum(d)
}
p
```

Comment: The above code works so that the movement between the discount levels is evaluated yearly. e.g no claims made in 1 year, move up discount level, claim made in next year, move down a discount level, and this is done according to a claim rate e.g 0.1. If we were to now change the time period to two years. e.g if no claims were made in year 1 or year 2, move up a discount level, now if 1 claim is made in year 1 or year 2, move back down a discount level, or if 2 or more claims were made over the two year period, drop to the 0% level of discount.

Comment: Can you help me to edit the code to account for this change in time period?

Comment: If the only change is moving from 1-year to 2-year windows then why does anything in the table need to change?  You matrix a has rows that represent years (0:20), and each element is the number of claims made by the user in column i that year.  If you want to move to 2-year windows, all you have to do is change the interpretation of the rows, from 1-year intervals to 2-year intervals.